# how to parse DHCP vendor-specific-info

Tags: isc-dhcp

Hello I would like to allocate IP based on the serial number as the mac address is not available without me connecting physical cable and login.
Tcpdump PCAP DHCP packet:

```
  TIME: 2023-10-27 09:58:33.159
    IP: 0.0.0.0
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: bc309003
  SECS: 0
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 00:0b:d3:31:fe:d2:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         7 (DHCPRELEASE)
OPTION:  54 (  4) Server identifier         10.0.0.189
OPTION:  43 ( 74) Vendor specific info      01074d514d393730 ..MQM860
                                            30020c4d514d3937 0..MQM97
                                            30302d4e53324603 00-NS2F.
                                            0c4d543232333158 .MT1111X. << serial
                                            32333034330406e8 23043...
                                            ebd331fed2051069 ..1....i
                                            622d73696e676c65 b-single
                                            2d73776974636806 -switch.
                                            09332e31312e3130 .3.11.10
                                            3134             14
OPTION:  60 (  6) Vendor class identifier   DELL
```

Here are the things I have tried, not working

```
host server1 {
  option dhcp-client-identifier = "MT1111X23043";
  fixed-address 10.0.0.40;
  option tftp-server-name = "http://10.0.0.18:8080/server/image/";
}
```

Serial is in option (43) how to send to dhcp server to allocate ip?